# Find two LI continuous differentiable functions $f,g: I \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $(f\cdot g')(t) - (f'\cdot g)(t)) = 0$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, wronskian

Find two linear independent continuous differentiable functions $f,g: I \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ with  $(f\cdot g')(t) - (f'\cdot g)(t)) = 0$.

Any idea on how can I find such functions? I imagine that, if $(f\cdot g')(t) - (f'\cdot g)(t)) = 0$, then:

$(f\cdot g')(t) = (f'\cdot g)(t)) \Longrightarrow \frac{f'}{f}(t) = \frac{g'}{g}(t) \Longrightarrow \ln(f(t)) = \ln(g(t)) + C \Longrightarrow f(t) = C \cdot g(t)$.

This implies $f,g$ are L.D., a contradiction. Maybe the trick is with choosing the right interval $I$ to define the functions. I don't know.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: At points where $f=0$ or $g=0$, $f'/f$ or $g'/g$ are not defined and it may happen that $C$ makes jumps there?

Comment: Good observation, still don't knowing the answer, but now i have some direction. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let $I=[-1,1]$. $f(t)=t^2$, $g(t)=t\left|t\right|$.